# Using Scala Array foreach function

Tags: scala, foreach

Here is my scala code:

```
val aa = Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,65)

val op = aa.foreach(str => str.toString.mkString("@@", "#", "%"))
```

I want the output to be:

```
(1@@#%,2@@#%,3@@#%,4@@#%,5@@#%,6@@#%,65@@#%)
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

`mkString()` takes a collection, and returns a string with the prefix followed by the collection elements joined by the 2nd argument, followed by the suffix. Hence you want:

```
val op = aa.map(str => str.toString + "@@#%"))
```

which will give you a collection of suitable strings. Your `foreach()` above iterates through the collection, but doesn't return anything. `map()` however will return a new transformed collection.

Note your code above doesn't specifically output your results. I would expect a `println` to work, but you may want to manipulate the output further using `mkString()` or similar.

Answer (score -2):

val aa = Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,5)

val op = aa.map(str => str.toString.mkString("[", ",", "]"))

op.foreach(println)

Comment: Your own answer doesn't give you the output you put in your question?